# ASM Compare 2 Numbers

Tags: numbers, compare, x86-16

My task is to compare two numbers in ASM. I input the first number (binary) and the second (binary). I must compare Z1 and Z2. If Z1>=Z2, show TRUE, else show FALSE

```
dane segment
txt1 db 'First number: $'
txt2 db 'Secend number: $'
z1 dw 0
z2 dw 0
prawda db 'True!$'
falsz db 'False!$'
dane ends

sts segment stack
db 256 dup(?)
sts ends

program segment
assume cs:program, ss:sts, ds:dane
start:
mov ax, seg dane
mov ds,ax 

mov dx, offset txt1
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov cx, 16
mov bx, offset z1
petla1:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
mov [bx], al
inc bx
loop petla1

mov cx, 16
mov ax, 0
mov bx, offset z1
petla2:
shl ax, 1
mov dl, [bx]
cmp dl, 31h
jne dal1
add ax, 1
dal1:
inc bx
loop petla2

mov dx, offset txt2
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov cx, 16
mov bx, offset z1
petla3:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
mov [bx], al
inc bx
loop petla3

mov cx, 16
mov ax, 0
mov bx, offset z1
petla4:
shl ax, 1
mov dl, [bx]
cmp dl, 31h
jne dal2
add ax, 1
dal2:
inc bx
loop petla4

;JGE, >= JNL not <
mov ax, [z1]
mov bx, [z2]
cmp ax,bx
jge ety
mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset falsz
int 21h
jae koniec

ety:
mov ah,9
mov dx, offset prawda
int 21h
koniec:

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
program ends
end start
```

What I do wrong? It's my first assembler project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov cx, 16
mov bx, offset z1
petla1:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
mov [bx], al
inc bx
loop petla1
```

You didn't reserve the necessary memory for this operation! *Z1* is defined as a word (2 bytes) and you are writing 16 bytes in this loop.
If you want to keep the basic structure of your program add the definition of a 16 byte buffer to recieve the binary representation of the number.

```
 Buffer  db  16 dup(0)

 mov cx, 16
 mov bx, offset Buffer
petla1:
 mov ah, 1
 int 21h
 mov [bx], al
 inc bx
 loop petla1

 mov cx, 16
 mov ax, 0
 mov bx, offset Buffer
petla2:
 shl ax, 1
 mov dl, [bx]
 cmp dl, 31h
 jne dal1
 add ax, 1
dal1:
 inc bx
 loop petla2

 mov [z1], ax
```

Do it similarly for the second number using the same *Buffer* but storing AX in *z2*.

Please note that the `jae koniec` should be an unconditional jump. `jmp koniec`